# How to keep search button from closing an AlertDialog?

Tags: android

If I create a standalone alertdialog with the builder (not connected to the activity/view) how can I keep the search button from causing the alertdialog to close?

Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea, but I'd love to see someone answer this one. Using the keyEvent class doesn't work as OnKeyUp/Down/Longpress doesn't execute when you touch the search key while a dialog box is open. I wonder if there's some other method that could be overridden.

Comment: Even I have the same problem.... any ideas people?

Comment: Do nothing on KeyEvent and onSearchRequested(). Did you tried that?

Comment: Have you tried `builder.setCancelable(false);`?

Answer (score 0):

That's really tricky, I have LayoutInflater in mind but that thing too needs to close.  Well a cheesy way to do that is have a View that you just do visible or invisible

Answer (score 0):

I'm also faced the same problem while showing EULA Dialog.
It was solved by setOnKeyListener.

here is the solution:

```
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity)
                    .setTitle(title)
                    .setMessage(message)
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new Dialog.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                            editor.putInt(Constants.EULA_VERSION, versionInfo.versionCode);
                            editor.commit();
                            dialogInterface.dismiss();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new Dialog.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // Close the activity once the EULA is declined.
                            mActivity.finish(); 
                        }

                    });

            //To avoid skipping EULA screen through search & menu button.
            builder.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {
                public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                    if (keyCode < KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP || keyCode > KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER) 
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                        return false;
                }
            });
            builder.create().show();
```